# System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'. nhibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, datetime, .net

I have the following classes:

```
public class AccionCorrectiva : Modelo<AccionCorrectiva>
{
    ...
    public virtual DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Indicador : Modelo<Indicador>
{        
    private IList<AccionCorrectiva> _acciones = new List<AccionCorrectiva>();
    public virtual IList<AccionCorrectiva> Acciones
    {
        get { return _acciones; }
        set { _acciones = value; }
    }
}
```

When I do `SomeIndicador.Acciones` I get:

`NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not initialize a collection: [Dominio.Indicador.Acciones#1][SQL: SELECT acciones0_.indicador_id as indicador8_1_, acciones0_.Id as Id1_, acciones0_.FechaFin as FechaFin1_, acciones0_.Id as Id6_0_, acciones0_.Hallazgo as Hallazgo6_0_, acciones0_.Descripcion as Descripc3_6_0_, acciones0_.Objetivo as Objetivo6_0_, acciones0_.FechaFin as FechaFin6_0_, acciones0_.NumEstado as NumEstado6_0_, acciones0_.responsable_id as responsa7_6_0_, acciones0_.indicador_id as indicador8_6_0_ FROM acciones_correctivas acciones0_ WHERE acciones0_.indicador_id=?] ---> System.FormatException: Input string '01/01/2013 0:00:00' was not in the correct format. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'.`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
If I call `AccionCorrectivaRepository.Instance.FindById(1)` I get an AccionCorrectiva and works fine!
The dialect is SQLite

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE acciones_correctivas (Id INT not null, FechaFin DATETIME);
```

**Mappings**
Indicador

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="Dominio"
                  namespace="Dominio">
  <class name="Indicador" table="indicadores">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <list name="Acciones" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="indicador_id" />
      <index column="FechaFin" />
      <one-to-many class="AccionCorrectiva" />
    </list>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

AccionCorrectiva:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                  assembly="Dominio"
                  namespace="Dominio">
  <class name="AccionCorrectiva" table="acciones_correctivas">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Indicador" column="indicador_id" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you provide your mapping for the classes. Also what DBMS are you using and what data type is `FechaFin` in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `<index>` mapping. See the documentation: [6.3. Collections of Values and Many-To-Many Associations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues)

Extract:

> For indexed collections like maps and lists, we require an `<index>`
>   element. For lists, this column contains sequential integers numbered
>   from zero. Make sure that your index really starts from zero if you
>   have to deal with legacy data. For maps, the column may contain any
>   values of any NHibernate type.

Other words, think about the *index* as the C# `IList` index (for example supporting the `list[0]` access). So, there must be column of int type (or smallint...), which NHibernate will use to track the `IList` indexes.